# Stopping an infinite reboot loop from /etc/rc.local

Tags: reboot

Long story short, an unfortunate series of development mistakes on my part has led */etc/rc.local* to quickly execute `reboot` (on a Pi in my case). The machine is now stuck in an infinite reboot loop.

Can I stop it? It reboots before the login prompt shows and I wouldn't have time to stop it even if it didn't.

Is there perhaps some magic keyboard shortcut that prevents /etc/rc.local from running?

I found [Exiting out of an infinite reboot loop in startup (rc.local)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87979/exiting-out-of-an-infinite-reboot-loop-in-startup-rc-local) here, but that actually deals with preemptive prevention of the issue, not fixing it after the fact. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a PC, you'd edit the kernel command line and (e.g.,) append one of:

- `systemd.unit=emergency.target` to get just a shell (requires systemd);
- `systemd.unit=rescue.target` to get some more stuff started, then a shell (requires systemd);
- `single` to boot to single-user mode, on SysV init systems. Not entirely sure this will avoid `rc.local` on Wheezy, though; or
- `init=/bin/bash`, which would avoid starting init at all, instead giving you a shell (where you could then remount the root filesystem read-write, and edit the broken file). I'm not entirely sure on a Pi, though, that this will give you a working keyboard. And it requires some knowledge as you'll be running without an init setting up the system for you; you can generally use `exec /sbin/init` to continue booting. (Works with *any* init system, because you completely bypass it).

I don't think there is a way to do that on a Raspberry Pi *unless* you're using NOOBS. In which case holding down shift should get you a recovery interface which will let you edit `cmdline.txt`—and this change the kernel command line. (Or, probably, just edit the broken file—I'd suggest doing that if possible)

The other alternative is to take your SD card out of the Pi, and use an SD card reader to mount either the boot partition (which I believe is FAT32, so you should be able to do this on Windows) or the root partition (which is likely ext4, so you'd need to be running Linux). Then you can either change the kernel command line in `cmdline.txt` or directly fix your `rc.local`. If you edit `cmdline.txt` on Windows, make sure to use an editor that understands Unix-style line endings and won't make a mess of them.

Personally, my approach would be to mount the Pi's root filesystem on a Linux box and edit the broken `rc.local`.

Once you've got your Pi booted again, remember to remove the any rescue options from `cmdline.txt`, of course.

Comment: Didn't even think of pulling the SD card; the Pi is mounted in another device. Easy enough to disassemble. Problem solved, thanks.

Comment: One can start up in *emergency* or *rescue* mode with just adjusted kernel command line arguments.

Comment: @JdeBP on a Raspberry Pi, there isn't a bootloader that lets you edit the kernel command line

Comment: I recommend reading your own answer, which talks about editing the kernel command line.  (-:  As I said, it takes no more than that to invoke _emergency_ or _rescue_ modes which are there for exactly such situations as this.  Whereas [abusing a shell for a process #1 program](http://askubuntu.com/a/638165/43344) is [not a good idea](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195889/).

Comment: @JdeBP nothing wrong with it, really. You just `exec /sbin/init` (to continue booting) or remount root r/o, sync, and hit reset (to reboot). But yeah, I'll edit to mention single (for Wheezy) and systemd emergency mode.

Comment: @JdeBP OK, I've listed a bunch of rescue options now, does that look better?